# how to use odeint's tag system to do specific work for various stepper types

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I have a templated class that can perform some work with odeint's stepper classes, and I want it to be a specific (different) work for each of the categories of steppers.

```
/// header file ///

template<class Stepper>
class foo {
    typedef typename boost::numeric::odeint::unwrap_reference< Stepper >::type::stepper_category stepper_category;
    void do_work(double param);
    // specific functions for various stepper types
    void do_specific_work(double param, stepper_category);
}

/// cpp file ///
template<class Stepper>
void foo<Stepper>::do_work(double param)
{
    do_specific_work(param, stepper_category());
}

// actual implementation of work for any stepper (i.e. exposing the basic functionality of stepper_tag)
template<class Stepper>
void foo<Stepper>::do_specific_work(double param, boost::numeric::odeint::stepper_tag)
{ ... }

// actual implementation of work for dense output stepper (i.e. exposing the functionality of dense_output_stepper_tag)
template<class Stepper>
void foo<Stepper>::do_specific_work(double param, boost::numeric::odeint::dense_output_stepper_tag)
{ ... }
```

The problem is that I get the following compiler error:

`error C2244: 'foo<Stepper>::do_specific_work' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration` `

I've tried to do it in the same way as the methods such as `integrate_adaptive` are implemented, the difference with my case is that those are stand-alone functions (not members of any class) and do not need forward declaration. How to modify the code to achieve what I need?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide explicit overloads for the specific categories:

```
template<class Stepper>
class foo {
    typedef typename boost::numeric::odeint::unwrap_reference< Stepper >::type::stepper_category stepper_category;

    // ...


    void do_specific_work(double param, stepper_tag );
    void do_specific_work(double param, dense_output_stepper_tag );
};

template< class Stepper >
void foo< Stepper >::do_specific_work( double param , stepper_tag )  { ... };

template< class Stepper >
void foo< Stepper >::do_specific_work( double param , dense_output_stepper_tag )  { ... };
```

You have one declaration do_specific_work( double param , stepper_category ) and several definitions. Your prototype does not match the definition right now.

Comment: Hi Karsten, thanks for your suggestion, it worked well. I've got another question: is it possible to bind a virtual member function of some class as the ODE system? namely, in documentation there is an example with a given class: `make_ode_wrapper( lorenz() , &lorenz::ode )`, but is it possible to write something like `

Comment: (continuing) is it possible to write something like `make_ode_wrapper( *myclass , &(myclass::ode) )` where `myclass` is a pointer to some class having a virtual function `ode` which performs the computation?

Comment: Yes, that should be very similar, maybe it even works with make_ode_wrapper. Otherwise you could also implement a small wrapper class taking a shared_ptr of a base class and calling the correct virtual method: `class virtual_wrapper  {   shared_ptr< my_class > b_;  virtual_wrapper( shared_ptr< my_class > b ) : b_( b ) {}  void operator()( State const&x , State &dxdt , Time t ) const  { b_->ode( x , dxdt , t ); }  };  `

Answer (score 1):

```
// actual implementation of work for any stepper (i.e. exposing the basic functionality of stepper_tag)
```

If you want this method to work with any stapper_tag than you have to use function template:

```
template<class StepperTag>
void do_specific_work(double param, StepperTag stepper);
```

And the implementation:

```
template<class Stepper>
template<class StepperTag>
void foo<Stepper>::do_specific_work(double param, StepperTag stepper)
{ ... }

template<class Stepper>
void foo<Stepper>::do_specific_work(double param, boost::numeric::odeint::dense_output_stepper_tag stepper)
{ ... }
```